# Generic Doubly Linked-list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, template, collections, classes

I am just learning about C++ templates and generic types, I decided it would be nice to try to create a generic container class as a challenge and test my knowledge in the process. Here is what I have come up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

template <typename __T>

class List{
private:
    struct node{
        __T data;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };
    typedef long long unsigned int c_size;
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    node* current;
    c_size m_S;

public:
    List()
        :head{NULL},tail{NULL},current{NULL},m_S{0}
    {}

    List(std::initializer_list<__T> __l)
        :head{NULL},tail{NULL},current{NULL},m_S{0}
    {
        for(auto const& elem:__l){
            insert_back(elem);
        }
    }
    void insert_front(__T _d){
        ++m_S;
        node* new_node{new node};
        new_node->data = _d;
        new_node->next = head;
        new_node->prev = NULL;

        if (head != NULL){
            head->prev = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = new_node;
        }
        head = new_node;

    }

    void print(){
        if (m_S == 0) return;
        node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL){
            std::cout << current->data << ", ";
            current = current->next;
        }
        std::cout << current->data << '\n';
    }

    void insert_back(__T _d){
        ++m_S;
        node* new_node = new node;
        new_node->data = _d;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        node* last = head;

        if (head == NULL) {
            new_node->prev = NULL;
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = new_node;
            new_node->prev = tail;
            tail = new_node;
        }
    }

    constexpr __T first(){
        assert(head != NULL && "Calling .front() on an empty list");
        return head->data;
    }
    constexpr __T last(){
        assert(tail != NULL && "Calling. last() on an empty list");
        return tail->data;
    }


    constexpr c_size size(){return m_S;}


    void remove_all(){
        current = head;
        while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
            delete current;
        }
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        current = NULL;
    }

};
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: _`__T`_ double underscores as prefix for a symbol are reserved for compiler internal implementations.

Comment: Hey, if you want some more practice you might want to align the interface of your `List` class with that of the standard `std::list`.

Comment: @slepic Hello, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I mean to use standard method names (along with their signatures), like push_back, push_front, back, front, pop_back, pop_front, clear, etc. You might also want to implement iterators and generally comply with c++'s container concept... You will get many general algorithms (like sort) for free just by following the interface of all standard containers.

Comment: And btw print is usually not part of generic container because it heavily depends on the generic value type T and the application itself.

Comment: @slepic wow really? I thought it would be a really bad idea to use the ones that are taken. The reason I did not try making the iterator part because I felt that it was a topic of its own  . I really appreciate all the information!

Comment: Can you please add a minimal `main` function demonstrating how you believe the class should be used?

Comment: @Peter I cannot edit the question now can I? It is again'st the guidelines,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Identifiers that start with a double underscore, or a single underscore followed by a capital letter, are reserved for use by the implementation. Your use of `__T` could conflict with this use.

Spacing is important. The blank line between `template <typename __T>` and the following `class List` line makes it harder to recognize the class as a template class.

What is the purpose of the `current` member? It is unnecessary.

`c_size` should probably be `std::size_t`, not `unsigned long long`. Because it is a private typedef, users of your class cannot access the type and can only declare a variable to hold the returned value using `auto`.

You don't declare the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, nor move assignment operators. This will cause problems with assignments of one `List` object to another.

`insert_head` and `insert_back` are very similar functions, but have been written somewhat differently. The implementation for `insert_back` can be made shorter by making it similar to `insert_head`. In particular, the assignment to `new_node->prev` can be done before the `if` (using `new_node->prev = tail;`, because when `head` is NULL, `tail` should also be), while the common `tail = new_node;` can be done after.

`first`, `last`, and `size` should also have the `const` modifier (e.g., `constexpr c_size size() const`.

`remove_all` will crash because you access `current->next` after `delete current`, nor do you delete the first (head) element.